# Call a method before destroySession in Java?

Tags: java, servlets, timeout

I need to perform a server-to-server call to an external application which, in turn, will send a request to my application rightaway. This need to be done before the session timeouts, so using a HttpSessionListener won't do the trick, as the session gets immediately invalidated there.

I would like a way to somehow do this call before the session timeouts and postpone the timeout for, for example, one minute more.

Any solutions?

Comment: If you're always extending the session by one minute right before its destroyed, wouldn't it then never expire?

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I want. I want to a way to execute my code before timeout. HtppSessionListener allows me to execute code during timeout, can I'm not able to postpone or cancel the timeout there.